# Is it possible to nest Composables inside UIKitView in Compose Multiplatform?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, compose-multiplatform

I basically want to make the UIKitView to ignore safeareas and nest a composable inside it.

Is it possible to do something like this in compose multiplatform?

```kotlin
@Composable
actual fun ExampleContainer(id: String) {
    UIKitView(
        modifier = Modifier,
        factory = {
            val view = UIView()
            view.addSubView() //Add composable as subview here
            view
        }
    )
}
```

Something like this should work, right?

```kotlin
fun getViewController(id: String) : UIViewController  = ComposeUIViewController {
    MyComposableView(id)
}
```

```kotlin
view.addSubView(getViewController(id).view)
```